# Django Rest do not show postgresql binary field in view

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

i have model called "Person" and i want to store profile pictures in database
in postgres i use "bytea" type for storing images and in my django model i use "BinaryField"

My model is like this:

```
class Person(models.Model)
    name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    photo = models.BinaryField(blank=True, null=True)
```

My Django serializer:

```
class PersonSerializer(modelserializer):
    class Meta:
        models = Person
        Fields= '__all__'
```

And finaly my view :

```
class PersonView(ModelViewSet):
    queryset= Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
```

my problem is that when i want to insert data django do not show "photo" field in the view
what is my mistake??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BinaryField` are not supported by Django REST framework. You'll need to write a serializer field class and declare it in a mapping to make this work.

Comment: thank you for help ,i am amator in django
how can i write a "serilizer field class" ??

Comment: it's explained there: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields